# pure PHP count down?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know there are ways of creating a countdown using Javascript. AJAX, etc. but I am working on a website that i cannot use javascript codes in the page that needs this countdown!

Basically, what I need to do is like this:

the website owner uploads an image (only 1 at a time and only 1 a day) and this image and its name and its ID will get stored in the Mysql database.

Now, on the front page of the site, this image will show properly (this bit works fine). I just need to know how I can create a simple countdown (24 hours countdown) using PHP as soon as the image was uploaded into the database and i will need to display this countdown right under that image on the front page.

first is there a simple way to do this using PHP only (purely PHP without javascript)?

and if so, how?

Comment: Do you want it to update in real-time? If so, I think that there is no unobstrusive way to do it without Javascript.

Comment: If you can't use javascript, you can't expect the page to update in real time. It can update on a page refresh though. Is that what you meant?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. It's not possible.

Comment: even to refresh the page every X time you would need javascript

Comment: As a variation on the page refresh theme, you could use a small iframe with just the countdown timer in it that autorefreshes to reduce the impact on your server...

Comment: @Naryl That's not true.

Comment: @mattedgod, not entirely sure what the difference is between real time and page refresh? I don't want it to re-start itself again once the user has refreshed the page or closed the page and reopened it.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I'm curious then, how to you tell a HTML page to be refreshed automatically in the browser of the client without using javascript?

Comment: @Naryl `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` ?

Comment: @DavidSmith because it's like asking if you can find the end of a rainbow. It's literally not possible and suggests a lack of understanding of the difference between server-side and client-side coding.

Comment: It is not impossible, as I showed in my post - just not recommended. I don't understand the downvotes either

Comment: @YounElan You've used both javascript and meta tags. The question was "pure PHP count down". Not possible. </debate>

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 no java script at all, the script is server side php - meta tags yes, this is a standard features available since the 90s

Comment: @YounElan The question was "pure PHP count down". Not possible. It is also important to debate the **value** of attempting a particular approach to a solution - hence the downvotes on both the question and your answer. If there were lots of upvotes, it would be mis-leading. And finally, refreshing the whole page would be phenomenally annoying for the end-user.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is [gifsockets](https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets). They function by streaming a GIF that is generated in real-time. You could generate a new frame every second (minute, whatever) and send that to the client. There is a PHP port of gifsockets at https://github.com/reactphp/gifsocket. Though really this is an esoteric answer to an esoteric question.

Answer (score 3):

Though I would recommend javascript, as I am bored, I figured it might be a fun exercise to try. Assuming you have access to the $_GET[] array, you can pass a counter variable to the script which returns a reference to itself with a decreasing parameter:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['counter']))
  {
    $counter=intval($counter)-5;
  }
  else
  {
    $counter=100;
  }
  if($counter<0) {
    //todo, insert what to do on time is 0
  }
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/?counter=<?php echo $counter; ?>">
```

I still recommend a different solution though

Comment: any examples of what you mentioned?

Comment: I just added code... though as I said in my post, I don't recommend it - most browser do support javascript

Comment: it doesn't make much sense but thanks anyway.. at least you've answered (even though it was out of your boredom) instead of downvotes  and bunch of useless comments...

Comment: It should work as long as you replace example.com with your server side url. the meta refresh tag basically tells the browser to reload the page to the specified url. you include the counter value in the url as a get parameter. The get parameter is decreased every time the page loads, it redirects to the page - except with a lower counter value

Comment: This solution doesn't account for any sort of network latency.

Comment: Actually it does account for network latency - the page reloads every 5 seconds... which should be fine. If it is not enough, make it 10 seconds. If the exact time is needed, you could even pass the exact time and implement additional logic

Comment: @YounElan Suppose it takes an extra second to load the page. Then the countdown is off by one second. The actual time must be passed for an accurate countdown.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Agreed, when you mentioned latency, I thought you were talking about time to load the page. To solve that issue, you can pass the timestamp of now if not provided. then 24h = 86400 - time() + $startTimestamp;

Comment: @YounElan: "network" latency